# Try - Catch around Enum

Tags: java

I want to save a method in an Enum, but Class.getDeclaredMethod is throwing NoSuchMethodException, so how can I handle it?
My Code:

```
public enum Card {

OPENPRISON(false, Cards.class.getDeclaredMethod("", Player.class));

private boolean isInstant;
private Method method;

private Card(boolean isInstant, Method method){
    this.method = method;
    this.isInstant = isInstant;
}

public boolean isInstant() {
    return isInstant;
}

public void run(Player p){

}
```

}

and OPENPRISON is the problem

Comment: What is "Cards" class. Is it some other class other than the Card enum?

Answer (score 1):

An immediate technical issue is that you're not providing a method name in your call to `getDeclaredMethod()`:

```
OPENPRISON(false, Cards.class.getDeclaredMethod("", Player.class));
```

A larger issue is why you need to use reflection at all.

An enum value is a constant. What can you do with reflection that you could not as easily do with a static method? Or with a method outside the enum?

Answer (score 0):

Well your code throws a checked exception, so you could use a method:

```
OPENPRISON(false, foo());

private static Method foo() {
    try {
        return Cards.class.getDeclaredMethod("", Player.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course, the question remains if you cannot solve your problem without reflection - most likely it is possible.